# There is no 'Animation' attached to the "person" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

[Picture: Object Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDUop.png)

I want to Play Animation when Virtual Button Pressed using Unity & Vuforia. But i don't know why i got an error **"there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object"**

I'm using Unity 4.7.0 and Vuforia 5-0-10

**This is the code that attached to the ImageTarget**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class VBEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, Vuforia.IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

public GameObject person;

void Start(){
    Vuforia.VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<Vuforia.VirtualButtonBehaviour> ();
    for(int i=0; i<vbs.Length; i++){
        vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }

    person = transform.FindChild("person").gameObject;
}

public void OnButtonPressed(Vuforia.VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    switch (vb.VirtualButtonName) {
        case "VBAnim":
            person.animation.Play();
            break;
    }
}

public void OnButtonReleased(Vuforia.VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    switch (vb.VirtualButtonName){
        case "VBAnim":
            person.animation.Stop();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that `Animation` component is attached to object? Better way is to use `Animator` instead and use e.g triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the error says

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

I'm thinking, it is very likely that

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

What you should do is check if

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

You may find that

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

If it turns out

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

then you've discovered the problem you're having,

> there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object

Heh!  It's that easy.

---

## 2019

Setting aside the humor, do note that these days

**You attach an `Animator`.  You don't, really, use animations directly.**

Review basic tutorials on animating humanoids in Unity.  ( [UMotion](https://www.soxware.com/umotion/) is highly recommended when working with animation in Unity.)

Comment: I have a suspicious feeling you're trying to tell him something... But I can't quite put my "there is no 'Animation' attached to the game object" on it.

Comment: Thank You Professor, Its Very 'Attached' for me